# Is it possible to delete multiple rows in MySQL if target table is in from clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHPMYAdmin and MySQL Database. I would like to remove from the table 1masterinventory all the rows (PK RID) that are not in 1amazoninventory (PK RID). I feel like this query should work but I get the error "#1093 - You can't specify target table '1masterinventory' for update in FROM clause."

```
 DELETE FROM 1masterinventory 
 WHERE rid IN
     (
        SELECT rid 
        FROM 1masterinventory 
        WHERE rid NOT IN
         (
           SELECT rid FROM 
           1amazoninventory WHERE 1
         )
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dba34/1/0):

```
DELETE m
FROM 1masterinventory m
LEFT JOIN 1amazoninventory a ON a.rid = m.rid
WHERE a.rid IS NULL;
```